# Where to apply the clearfix class

Tags: html, css, clearfix

So I'm having a problem with the last paragraph apparently not clearing and slipping into the middle of the `h1` and `nav`. But when I put a div with a clear:both property before the paragraph it appears to work.

Bear with my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4tma/6/), please.

- I used a purple background to represent the image replacement technique that I learned from nettuts.
- The clearfix part is a class named "group", the CSS is at the bottom.
- Also if I remove the `display:block;` from `h1 > a` the layout breaks so a follow up question is, what elements should I float and where should I apply the clearfix.

Comment: Is the `p` meant to be part of the header? or should the top edge of the `p` be below the links or `nav` group?

Comment: @MarcAudet Yes, I'm sorry I missed that. The `p` is still inside the `header`. Basically I have some other elements after the `nav` and I just replace all of them with a single `p` element to simplify the code while still showing the problem.

Comment: it's difficult to understand what you want, can you show the picture how you want?

Comment: @C-Link
basically want I want is for the paragraph to sit below the 2 floated elements. Just like if I applied `clear:both;` to the paragraph but instead I'm trying to accomplish that result without clearing it and instead using the clearfix technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing arises because the clearing element is in the wrong place.

Consider your CSS:

```
h1 {
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    background: red;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    border: 1px dashed cyan;
}
nav {
    height: 44px;
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
    background: black;
    border: 1px dashed cyan;
}
.group:after {
    content:"x";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

You have `h1` floated left and `nav` floated right, and then you have your `p` block with your text (not floated).

The `p` content wraps around the two floated elements as expected unless you add the `clear:both` rule to `p` as pointed out earlier.

The clearing element has to appear in the DOM **after** the `nav` element.

In this example, you apply `.group` to `nav`, which generates content that appears after the `ul` block that is a child of the `nav` block.

The problem becomes more obvious is you set the `nav` height to `auto` and you add some borders and colors to show the edges of the various blocks.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/9nGQy/

The problem can be seen as follows:

[image]

I added an `x` to mark the spot in your generated content for the clearing element, which appears within the `nav` block.

Comment: Oh, well now I'm puzzled as to why the x (:after content) is appearing inside the `nav`; isn't it supposed to appear after it? I was imagining it to be between the `nav` and `p`. Since now I realize that I'm floating and clearing things wrong. What and where should I float and clear to achieve the intended result?

Comment: The pseudo-elements selectors `:after` and `:before` generate content that is inserted inside the element to which the the pseudo-element selectors are applied. The `clear: both` need to be applied to the `p` element in your example.

Comment: So what you're saying is: The `:before` part is actually after the opening `<nav>` tag and the `:after` is before the closing one (`</nav>`)?

Comment: I didn't know where I read about these pseudo elements but they explained that the content is generated before and after the element. I feel so deceived. Anyway now that I know the wrong I've been doing, I guess I can't ask any more. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
p{
   clear:both;
}
```

It should work for you depending what the outcome is you are after.

Comment: well yes, that works similar to adding a div and applying clear:both to it, what I'm wondering about is why the clearfix isn't working. Isn't the clearfix technique supposed to save us from having to clear elements after each floated element by applying the clearfix class instead of clearing all elements after each floated one?

Comment: @kentz clearfix allows the element to clear after _itself_. Usually it's used when all of the children are floated since that removes them from the normal flow. It's actually not even necessary in this case because it will contain the last `p` tag since it's not floated and it's below all the other floated elements.

Comment: @thgaskell Yes exactly. Since I floated the `nav`, I thought applying the clearfix to it would cause the paragraph to appear below it as if I used `clear:both;` on the paragraph but it seems to have no effect instead.

Comment: Sorry, I actually thought the clearfix was applied to the header. The `clear: both` is actually applied to the pseudo-element that comes after the `.group` element. There aren't any floated elements inside your `nav` so it's not doing anything. But to be clear, clearfix makes it so your the element contains the floated elements that can normally pop out of it since they're removed from the flow.